# uncaught rangeError

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this jsfiddle set up with a script that takes the value of 4 sliders and subtracts it from a total.  The script is working perfectly, but when I upload it to the server, I get an "uncaught rangeError" message.  I'm not sure how to get rid of it.  I don't want to change the functionality in anyway, I just want to get rid of the error message.

http://jsfiddle.net/mysticgohan53/A2YsU/16/

Comment: Share the link to server, if possible.

Comment: Well, thanks for freezing my Firefox for 2 minutes `:P` That fiddle throws "too much recursion".

Comment: @thecodeparadox - I can't give you a link, but I can give you this screen grab - http://screencast.com/t/ax0DQcL1U24L

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - any idea on how to clean it up without changing the functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fiddle with the correct answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/mysticgohan53/A2YsU/19/

I moved the refresh into the if/else statement and that seems to have worked. I would imagine that it has something to do with recursion like @SimeVidas was saying.

Unfortunately, I'm not a javascript ninja, so I can't really tell why this is working now.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging your code I saw `.slider('refresh')` is creating the problem. commenting out lines containing `.slider('refresh')` should solve the problem.

update jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/A2YsU/17/).

Comment: Removing the refresh changes the functionality. I need the slider to stop when the user reaches the value.